# sed: delete all lines in a file using sentinel values

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to do an inclusive delete from a file that looks like the following:

```
Some text
Some text
#$
Should be deleted
Should also be deleted
#$
More text
```

I want the file to read the following after sed is ran through it:

```
Some text
Some text
More text
```

the `#$` values should be inclusively removed.

Can someone explain the sed command used to do this as well?

Comment: `sed -e '/\#\$/,/\#\$/g' -e '/^$/d' your_file.txt > new_file.txt` should do the trick. The first part removes all the text between the two things, not much to explain, just sed syntax. The second part takes care of the left over blank lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/^#\$/,/^#\$/d' file
```

The idea is to match from the first time you see `#$` to the second time, and then delete it.

Comment: you need to remove the `a` in `^\#\$a`

Comment: Is there really a need to escape the hash?